# Binding ListBox to List in Silverilght not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding

All,

I have what i think is the simplest example possible of data binding in silverlight... but clearly even that is too complicated for me :)

The XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
<ListBox x:Name="rblSessions">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SessionTitle}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="30" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Sessions> theSessions = makeSessions();
            rblSessions.ItemsSource = theSessions;
            rblSessions.DataContext = theSessions;

        }

        public List<Sessions> makeSessions()
        {
            List<Sessions> theReturn = new List<Sessions>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Sessions s = new Sessions() { SessionID = i, SessionTitle = string.Format("title{0}", i) };
                theReturn.Add(s);
            }
            return theReturn;
        }

    }

    public class Sessions
    {
        public int SessionID;
        public string SessionTitle;
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I get a listbox with 20 elements in it, but each element is empty, and only about 5 pixels tall (though I set FontSize to "30")

What am I doing wrong? Help please and thanks

/jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make your Session class members into properties in order to use them in a binding. This should fix it:

```
public class Sessions
{
    public int SessionID { get; set; }
    public string SessionTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh my! How did I overlook that? Thanks *so* much
/jonathan